# https with name of company in address bar

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I don't know how to name it, so I can't search for it.

I have a website with a Let's encrypt SSL certificate running with nginx and I would like to display the name of the company in the address bar like this:
[image]

Is it possible with Let's encrypt? I've seen it only for banks, maybe it's too complicated.

Comment: Side note: You almost certainly don't need one. You'll note that Google, Facebook, Amazon, etc. don't bother with them.

Comment: In the future major browsers won't show the company name in the address bar anymore. Read [this](https://serverfault.com/q/926974/483945) and save your money!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible with Let's Encrypt. You need to buy an [extended validation certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate) with a commercial registrar, provide documentation to prove your identity and prepare to pay a large sum of money for this.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does anyone how much is it?

Comment: You can check for yourself, just visit some CA and check their prices.

Comment: …not only "provide documentation" but also undergo a formal validation process requiring answering phone calls by several persons in one's enterprise and being listed in one or more official "enterprise directories" (such as Yellow Pages FWIW). A boring and time-consuming process :-)

Comment: You can get a Geotrust True BusinessID EV certificate for around $130 a year or a Comodo PositiveSSL EV certificate for around $77 a year, prices found [here](https://www.gogetssl.com/extended-validation/) - I have no affiliation with that site.  Those are for single-domain certs, multi-domain certs cost more.  The price premium is justified by the work they have to do to prove your business's identity.